# iOs Geolocation Pin from PHP/MySql Server

Tags: iphone, mysql, ios, web-services, geolocation

I am making an application that implement MkMapView with location from a DataBase.
I've already made a login system and it works :

1. There is a in-App Form (pseudo, pw), the user log
2. It connect to a PHP file,
3. The file do my request to the server and if information are right the user is logged.

Now i want to get information from this same server like the couple : latitude/longitude or the place's adress.

I want to get something like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5e4n.png

I've already set up the table all i want is to retrieve these data wich are going to be updated every x min or when the user tap the refresh button.

Here is my PHP file request (Edited):

```
<?php


    $result = login();
    $json = array();
    $i = 0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){


    $row['Nom'] = mb_check_encoding($row['Nom'], 'UTF-8') ? $row['Nom'] : utf8_encode($row['Nom']);
    $row['Adresse'] = mb_check_encoding($row['Adresse'], 'UTF-8') ? $row['Adresse'] : utf8_encode($row['Adresse']);

    //Associations des resultats
        $json['locations'][$i]= array(
            'adresse' => $row['Adresse'],
            'nom' => $row['Nom'],
            'latitude' => $row['latitude'],
            'longitude' => $row['longitude']
        );  
        $i++;
    }

    //Encodage du tableau en JSON
    echo json_encode($json);
    echo "<br>";


//FONCTION
function makeSqlConnection()
{
$DB_HostName = "localhost";
$DB_Name = "DB";
$DB_User = "USER";
$DB_Pass = "PW";

    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 

        mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

    return $con;
}

function disconnectSqlConnection($con)
{
    mysql_close($con);
}

function login()
{
    $con = makeSqlConnection();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM  Parking";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());


    /*while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        echo $r['Adresse'] . " " . $r['Nom'];
        echo "<br>";
        $rows[] = $r;
    }*/

    disconnectSqlConnection($con);

    return $res;
}// end of Function 
?>
```

Update, now it works:

{"locations":[{"adresse":"52 Rue du Commerce, 75015 Paris","nom":"une otra cos\u00e9","latitude":"48.846481","longitude":"2.295336"},{"adresse":"80, rue de la Convention 75015 PARIS","nom":"una cosa","latitude":"48.842136","longitude":"2.285587"}]}

I need to make an architecture that I can reuse for android later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is very good tutorial to start with: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial

---

Regarding your PHP code:

You can edit while to display JSON and then retrive it within the app.

```
$json = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $json['locations'][] = array(
        'adresse' => $row['Adresse']. " " . $row['Nom'],
        'latitude' => HERE_LATITUDE_OF_LOCATION_FROM_DB,
        'longitude' => HERE_LONGITUDE_OF_LOCATION_FROM_DB
    );
}
$json = mb_check_encoding($json, 'UTF-8') ? $json : utf8_encode($json);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Then iOS part with AFNetworking:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourserver.com/api/locations"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    for (NSDictionary *location in [JSON objectForKey:@"locations"]) {
        /*
         add here your location to the MKMapView using
         annotation (get lat, lon using [location objectForKey:@"latitude"];)
        */
    }
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

Comment: Yep i've already read this but he is pars ing a JSON file. My data should be updated Evert x minutes si i shouldn't download every time the file right ?

Comment: Why not? Every x minutes is not that often. You can use timestamp to collect data that changed since last fetch. It depends on your server implementation.

Comment: Alright, so according to you, I should do my request and then parse the returned result into a JSON (or XML) file ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can use AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for connection. It has class `AFJSONRequestOperation` so you will get your results already parsed.

Comment: Nice ! But I've one more problem AFJSONRequestOperation is for "Download and Parse JSON" so the file is already on the server how can I use it with a PHP Request ?

Comment: You can point your AFJSONRequestOperation URL to php file which generates JSON data as I saw you in the example :)

Comment: Do the JSon encode work for y ou I get a `Warning: json_encode() [function.json-encode]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence`

Comment: It's because you have no-UTF-8 chars in your DB. You can follow that article to change them to UTF-8: http://www.johnro.net/2011/06/10/php-warning-json_encode-function-json-encode-invalid-utf-8-sequence-in-argument-in-god_i_hate_this-php/. But first you can remove them for testing.

Comment: so i do `$json= mb_check_encoding($json, 'UTF-8') ? $json: utf8_encode($json)` ?

Comment: Thanks you ! with few modifications it did the tricks ! I had to encode the `$row[value]` like `$row['Value'] = mb_check_encoding($row['Value'], 'UTF-8') ? $row['Value'] : utf8_encode($row['Value']);`. And I had to add a variable `$i` to `$json['locations'][$i]` (that's also why I didn't understood why it was a bidmensional array). Now I'll try to get the echo in my app.